# Android application cannot acces Internet

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

My application can access internet through the avd emulator but as soon as I use it on my phone or I use my phone as an emulator. I got the UnknownHostException I double checked that I was on the wifi and I changed the manifest with:

`<uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

And I added this code on my class:

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I repeat I have no problem to access internet through my AVD but not with my phone :S

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sslclient);

    //Allowing to access the network
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    //Getting the GUI user input information
    web_address_et              = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    port_number_et              = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    connection_information_tv   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            findViewById(R.id.button2).setBackgroundColor(color.button_material_dark);
            if (web_address_et.getText().toString().matches("") 
                || port_number_et.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                connection_information_tv.setText("Please fill the URL and Port# fields!");
            }

            else {
                try {
                    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(web_address_et.getText().toString());

                    //Android native behavior (do not accept untrusted certificate)
                    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
                    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)socketFactory.createSocket(host, Integer.parseInt(port_number_et.getText().toString()));

                    socket.startHandshake();
                    printSSLSessionInfo(socket, socket.getSession());
                    socket.close();

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    }
            }
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundColor(color.button_material_dark);
            findViewById(R.id.button2).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            if (web_address_et.getText().toString().matches("") 
                || port_number_et.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                connection_information_tv.setText("Please fill the URL and Port# fields!");
            }

            else {
                try {
                    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(web_address_et.getText().toString());

                    //Naive custom TrustManager (empty checkServerTrusted)
                    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                    TrustManager trustManagerNaive =    new X509TrustManager(){
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void checkClientTrusted(
                                                                    X509Certificate[] chain,
                                                                    String authType)
                                                                    throws CertificateException {
                                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                                return null;
                                                            }

                                                            @Override
                                                            public void checkServerTrusted(
                                                                    X509Certificate[] chain,
                                                                    String authType)
                                                                    throws CertificateException {
                                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                            }
                                                        };

                    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManagerNaive}, new SecureRandom());

                    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory)sslContext.getSocketFactory();
                    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)socketFactory.createSocket(host, Integer.parseInt(port_number_et.getText().toString()));

                    socket.startHandshake();
                    printSSLSessionInfo(socket, socket.getSession());
                    socket.close();

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    } catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        connection_information_tv.setText(e.toString());
                    }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Strict mode to run network on ui thread has been done away with a few versions back. Not sure which one. Are your phone and emulator running the same flavors of android?

Answer (score 1):

> UnknownHostException

is sometimes related to a resource that you can´t access, probably you are using :

`http://localhost` or `http://your_IP`

Your domain must be a valid domain, that you can access from your computer and  from your mobile device.

Comment: No it is not on the emulator I can access google, youtube or whatever and on my phone this exception is always rising!

Comment: Yes but the url that you are trying to access probably isn´t available in your phone.